# Skiller Android SDK: Adding a buddy while playing a game?

Tags: android, multiplayer

Hoping to find some Skiller experts to answer this. I've been using Skiller for developing my game for last 3 weeks. The Skiller documentation does not explain how a player can add a buddy while playing a game? Is that possible? If that's the case, is that documented anywhere?

From the SDK documentation, I can see that BUDDY_LIST is an optional argument to call the showScreen() method but I don't know whether it work during game play? Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am VP R&D at Skiller, thanks for using our SDK.
To shorten the integration time and at the same time give the developers many additional elements to their game and make it more appealing, many things were implemented for the developers. You don't need to implement all the community features from the scratch. We do it for you and expose many tools to communicate and manage the community.

In current and previous Skiller SDK versions all you need to do is raise the buddy list window and the window in its turn already implements all the functionality of adding/removing/searching for buddies.

In the next version of the SDK we will expose the API using which you will be able to add the last opponent that your user played against as a buddy.

If you have any other questions I can help you with please send email to developers@skiller-games.com or visit our developers forum on [www.skiller-games.com](http://www.skiller-games.com)